# 12M Measure total problem in Power BI DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I am currently facing an issue with DAX. I have a 12 Months Rolling measure which is used per customer category in a table visual in Power BI.

The issue is that the total row displayed is not equal to the sum of the individual rows. 
I have been looking for days for a solution. My 12 Months Rolling measure is quite complex. I have tried using the SUMX; Hasonefilter; Hasonevalue functions but I did not manage to find a proper solution.

Here is the formula I am using to display the 12M Rolling measure :

```
12M Rolling Sales =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( [Sales Amount] ),
    DATESBETWEEN (
        'Dates'[Date],
        NEXTDAY ( SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR ( LASTDATE ( 'Dates'[Date] ) ) ),
        LASTDATE ( 'Dates'[Date] )
    )
)
```

Attached, you can see what problem I am facing
[Simplified 12 Months Rolling Sales Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYXFy.png)

Thank you for the support

Comment: could you please post your data model diagram, and a screenshot of the report with all visuals that might be affecting the measure (slicers etc)? A data sample or a pbix file would be great too.

Comment: How about a flag in the query editor? Put the logic of the flag there and then simply put your `Sales Amount` column into a visual (with sum aggregation) and filter the flag (in this visual) to `TRUE`. If you add more details about the logic of your calculation (the flag) I could assist you further.